# C# Cefsharp - Open popup in parent broswer - ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

I have a ChromiumWebBrowser that handles the LifespanHandler event. When a popup is about to open, I want to open it in the browser parent. Here's a code found in internet:

```
    bool ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        //get url popup
        if (this.popup_request != null)
            this.popup_request(targetUrl);
        
        //stop open popup
        newBrowser = null;
        return true; 
    }
```

I need the popup browser (not the url) itself, since it is posted with data, if I open only the url in the parent browser the page won't work.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/89/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Handlers/LifeSpanHandler.cs for an example, you'll also need https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/89/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Helper/PopupAsChildHelper.cs

Comment: @amaitland thanks for your response, but how can I open the popup window in the parent ChromiumWebBrowser? I have the popup url but I need to open the popup with the posted data

Comment: As in you'd like to avoid opening the popup and just have the request load as a normal form submit?

Comment: some data is sent when opening the popup, so it won't work if I do this: ((ChromiumWebBrowser)browserControl).Load(targetUrl); It does open the popup page in the parent browser but without the expected results that would be shown in a real web browser... I'm newbie in cefsharp =/

Comment: If you'd like the form post to continue the the browser it was created rather than opening in the popup then you'll have to modify the html form. You can in most cases do this dynamically via JavaScript,  get all form elements, loop through them and remove the target attribute. You can use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/89.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded.htm to execute JavaScript upon page load.

Comment: If the form data is small you could also consider changing from a post to a get so your code above works. Using JavaScript that is.

Comment: Great! It was solved by changing (with javascript) the target of the form to _self. Thanks!